# How can I tell if an authorize.net transaction has settled?

Tags: python, authorize.net

In cases where I need to cancel an order, I need to know whether to void or refund the transaction.  I'm trying to learn whether the transaction has settled using the Transaction Details API.

`transactionDetailsResponse.transaction.transactionStatus` seems like it might be the right thing to look at. Does anyone know what the possible values are for `transactionStatus`.  At this point, I'm only in the sandbox where there is only one value, `capturedPendingSettlement`.

Do transaction in the sandbox settle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the right place to look. The possible values for that field are:

- uthorizedPendingCapture
- capturedPendingSettlement
- communicationError
- refundSettledSuccessfully
- refundPendingSettlement
- approvedReview
- declined
- couldNotVoid
- expired
- generalError
- failedReview
- settledSuccessfully
- settlementError
- underReview
- voided
- FDSPendingReview
- FDSAuthorizedPendingReview
- returnedItem

Items in the sandbox *do* settle.

Comment: A rep on the phone thought sandbox transactions didn't settle.  You saved me a bit of a headache here.   Thanks.